# Unable to use Auto Mapper with .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am unable to use Auto Mapper with .net core 2.2. It's keep throwing this error :

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ======================================================================================================================================================================================================= AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be
>   mapped using the current configuration. IDataReader -> List`1
>   (Destination member list) System.Data.IDataReader ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Models.EngineModel,
>   Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: Capacity

Here is my EngineModel class:

```cs
public class EngineModel
{
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public int engineNo { get; set; }

        public string engineHost { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Profile:

```cs
    public class EngineMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public EngineMappingProfile()
        {

            CreateMap<IDataReader, EngineModel>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Id , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(src.GetOrdinal("ID"))))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.engineNo , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetInt32(src.GetOrdinal("ENG_NO"))))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.engineHost , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(src.GetOrdinal("ENG_HOST"))))

        }
    }
```

Here is my Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```cs
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<EngineMappingProfile>();
            });
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                });
        }
```

All above code is in my API Project. I am using these profile in my Business Project:

```cs
 var enginesData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<EngineModel>>(dataReader.mcDataReader);
```

I am using "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection (6.0.0)" and "AutoMapper (8.0.0)

Comment: It looks like you may be missing a profile. You show a profile for mapping `IDataReader` -> `EngineModel`, but you're actually trying to map `IDataReader` -> `List<EngineModel>`.

Comment: It used to work without any issue in .net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install [AutoMapper.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Data/3.0.0) (3.0.0 in your situation) from the NuGet Packages and then add below code in startup:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();
});
```

Refer to

[Automapper Map DataTable to POCO list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622192/automapper-map-datatable-to-poco-list)

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/50

Comment: Yeah I figured this out. Also, instead of IDataReader, IDataRecord should be used in the mapping:

  CreateMap<IDataRecord, EngineModel>()

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper is complaining because `IDataReader` has other properties you haven't specified. You either need to map them all (which in this case is obviously not needed) or specify that they should be ignored, for example:

```
        CreateMap<IDataReader, EngineModel>()
           .ForMember(...)
           .ForMember(...)
           .ForMember(...)
           .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore()); // < -- Add this line
```

Comment: same error. Even though I have added this but there are no other members in the class. All the members have been mapped. There is another thing I noticed that even If I don't provide that profile in the startup.cs. It throws me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same version as your so this is how I condif my automapper

In my startup.cs I only need this

```
services.AddAutoMapper(config => config.ValidateInlineMaps = false);
```

And how I create Profile class

```
public class CommentProfile : Profile
{
    public CommentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Comment, CommentDto>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class Comment : BaseEntity
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class CommentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqeId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Comment ParentComment { get; set; }
    public CommentStatus CommentStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Adding that to services.AddAutoMapper is throwing the same error. But If I do this, it doesn't throw any error but then nothing has been mapped as well.
`code`
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<EngineMappingProfile>();
            });
            services.AddAutoMapper();
`code`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just:

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

That registers `IMapper` in the service collection and applies all profiles in the namespace (any class that inherits from `Profile`) automatically.

Then, you should be injecting `IMapper`, not using the static `Mapper`. In your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public MyController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
```

Then, when you want to map something:

```
 var enginesData = _mapper.Map<List<EngineModel>>(dataReader.mcDataReader);
```

However, you can't directly map an `IDataReader` instance to a list, which is your main problem. You need to enumerate the data reader storing the rows as items in a list, and then you can map from that list to your `List<EngineModel>`. Though, it would probably make more sense at that point to literally just read the rows out as `EngineModel` and build the list as you enumerate the data reader. Then there's no need to map at all.

Comment: This used to work fine in .net framework Web API. It will be really inefficient to loop through the data reader and map single row at a time

Comment: @Imran Khan I would use `ProjectTo` - so `var enginesData = _mapper.ProjectTo<EngineModel>(dataReader.mcDataReader);`

Comment: What do you think AutoMapper would be doing? Same thing.